# How to complete missing data in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm having so trouble trying to fill in missing rows in a simple df

```
x <- data.frame( "Name" = c("John","Dora"), "Age" = c(21,15))
```

I always need a 2x2 dataframe and sometimes are John or Dora missing. I need the output to fill in John or Dora under Name with age of '0' when missing.

Here is what I'm trying

```
x[1, ] %>% 
       tidyr::complete(tidyr::nesting('John' , 'Dora'), fill = list('Age' = 0))
```

And it give me this error

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `"John"`, `"Dora"` which is missing from RHS
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In seq.default(along = x) :
partial argument match of 'along' to 'along.with'
2: In seq.default(along = x) :
partial argument match of 'along' to 'along.with'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expand using factor levels in `complete` :

```
tidyr::complete(x, Name = factor(Name, levels = c('John', 'Dora')), 
                   fill = list(Age = 0))
```